# What does it mean to say that a set is radical in Banach Algebra

Tags: notation, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $B$ be a commutative unital Banach algebra. Let $$R(B)=\{x\in  B: r(x)=0\}$$ be a radical of $B$. Show that $R(B)$ is closed ideal of $B$.

Here I am confused with the term radical. What does it mean?

Please help.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but a radical of an ideal $I$ is $\sqrt{I}=\{x\in R: x^n\in I$ for some $n\}$

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include where this quote comes from?

Comment: What's $r$? Without this knowledge, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, we should have 
$$R(B)=\{x\in B:\forall r\in\Omega(B),r(x)=0\},$$
where $\Omega(B)$ is the character space of $B$ (i.e. the set of all nonzero multiplicative functionals on $B$).  In which case, in the notation I've seen, $R(B)$ is *the* radical of $B$, which is defined as the intersection of all maximal ideals of $B$.

Comment: question is given in my home assignment, and i had written it exactly it is given in assignment.  i think you are wright. then how can we show that $R(B)$ is closed ideal of $B$

Comment: Maximal ideals are closed (this is fairly easy to show).  Thus $R(B)$ is the intersection of closed sets, hence closed, and is the intersection of ideals, hence an ideal.